# Why don't I get a type error when combining these apparently-incompatible objects with the spread operator?

Tags: typescript

Here's my minimal reproduction:

```
const br: Record<string, number> = {"b": 0};
const ar: {a: string} = {a: ""};
const brar: Record<string, string> = {...ar, ...br};
console.log(brar);
```

It seems to me like `brar` should not be allowed, since it claims to have only values of type `string`, but contains a `number` at key `"b"`. Yet the typescript playground seems to [accept it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBARgJwFwwEoFNQICYB5oICWYA5gDQxgCuAtnOggHwwC8MA3gERycoAMAXwDcAKFCRYAQ2QdJKAsRIDWslJ07Cx4aPATSUGLHgWkKJkszbsAdLekVb1xJvEQQAG3TX3IEgApEaQBKISA). What's going on?

Some changes that seem to cause a type error to arise:

- using `Record<"b", number>` for `br`, or using no type signature at all,
- using `Record<string, string>` for `ar` (though `Record<"a", string>` is fine).

edit: it turns out `ar` can be inlined, leading to an arguably [even more minimal reproduction](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=3&ssc=18&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBARgJwFwwEoFNQICYB5oICWYA5gDQxgCuAtnOggHwwC8MA3nCgAwC+A3AChQkWAENEKDFjwFi5GHNLM27MSgBEGigDo9iAcPAQQAG3Q7TIEgAoJCAJT8gA):

```
const br: Record<string, number> = {b: 0};
const abr: Record<string, string> = {a: "", ...br};
console.log(abr);
```

Comment: Interesting. I don't know the answer yet, but if you leave out the type of `brar` (ie `const brar = {...ar, ...br};` instead, its type is inferred as `{a: string}` only - which is also wrong but in line with your result. Seems that TS just drops the index signature when composing `brar`, but no idea why.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27273